# How do I connect my login screen with my home screen after I login?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a login screen and wanted to connect it with my home page after I log in. I created a Segue with Identifier but It doesn't work when I try it. What can I do?

```swift
let message = json!["message"] as? String

if (message?.contains("success"))!
{                                                   
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "homelogin", sender: self)

    let id = json!["id"] as? String
    let name = json!["name"] as? String
    let username = json!["username"] as? String
    let email = json!["email"] as? String


    print(String("Emri") + name! )
    print(String("Emaili") + email! )
    print(String("Id") + id! )
    print(String("username") + username! )                                                      
}
else
{
    print(String("check your password or email"))
}
```

[this is the segue with Identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYxZ0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of issues with your code. Try it and let me know if it works. I have also added explanation for the changes I done.

```
if let json = json { // The “if let” allows us to unwrap optional values safely only when there is a value, and if not, the code block will not run and jump to else statement

    let message = json["message"] as? String ?? "" // The nil-coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil. 

    if message == "success" {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "homelogin", sender: self)
        }

        let id = json["id"] as? String ?? "" // String can directly be entered in double quotes. no need to use String()

        let name = json["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let username = json["username"] as? String ?? ""
        let email = json["email"] as? String ?? ""



        print("Emri " + name )
        print("Emaili " + email )
        print("Id " + id )
        print("username " + username )


    }else{
        print("check your password or email")
    }
} else {
    print("Invalid json")
}
```

Comment: still not working Thread 8: Exception: "threading violation: expected the main thread" and it shows this error on the console "Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]
PID: 4213, TID: 269619, Thread name: (none), Queue name: NSOperationQueue 0x7fd4fd430bd0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED), QoS: 0"

Comment: https://www.writeurl.com/text/pd6d3dk7mebtex8q4m26/ufobc5xnyke16uke2tc0
this is the whole code